# Objective c error, while trying to start up a project with encryption

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

i have this problem for which i don't know from where it comes. Can anyone help me with this?
this is the error:

http://img801.imageshack.us/img801/3364/theerror.png

I'm trying to use this class for encryption, which i found in this site: 
http://greghaygood.com/2009/01/17/symmetric-encryption-with-the-iphone-sdk-and-securityframework.

When i'm traying to

Comment: Fix those warnings and you will fix your error. The error descriptions are pretty clear. It looks like you didn't import the framework correctly.

Comment: Thnx, but do you know which framework to import for this reference, cause i imported a lot of frameworks like: Security framework and others but always with error happens.

Comment: Did you actually add the framework to your project or did you just import it?

Comment: I added from "Link Binary With Libraries" which is under "Build Phases" menu, where are all frameworks.

Comment: http://img35.imageshack.us/img35/1445/capture2rm.png those frameworks i added, here i imported from other project: SecurityInterface.frameword

Comment: Can you show me the code where you call doCipher?

Comment: Actually i didn't call, i just tried to build but it doesn't let me because of the strange functions LOGGING_FACILITY and LOGGING_FACILITY1 which i don't understand and i don't know how to implement those functions in the program. It gives this warning before building: "Implicit declaration of function "LOGGING_FACILITY" is invalid in C99".

Comment: Yeah, I understand that, but you wrote the method call somewhere in your code right?

Answer (score 0):

You referencing Logging_Facility and its not in the project.

Exactly What @sosborn has stated above, the frameworks where not inputted correctly and from the look at the error image theirs are quit a few things out of place.

Fix that and you will have a clean working app.

Comment: Thnx, but do you know which framework to import for this reference, cause i imported a lot of frameworks like: Security framework and others but always with error happens.

Comment: With not being able to review the source code, its hard to say. Best experience i would tell you to read your errors line by line and try to make sure all those references its referring to are in your frameworks. Also If this answer was of help, UP Vote or Mark it as an Answer....That's What we Do here on Stack! :))